# Determining the rotation shape

Tags: rotations, affine-geometry, geometry

Consider a large number of points distributed on the circumference of a circle with radius *r*. If I rotate each point with a randomly chosen Euler angle around a randomly chosen coordinate inside this circle, then the result of this transformation may not be distributed within the circle and it may exceed the circle's dimension. I am interested in the calculation (and drawing) of the largest possible shape (or dimension) that this transformation can make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximal shape is a circle with thrice the radius of the original. You can obtain it by rotating every point on the rim around another point on the rim directly opposite (i.e. antipodal) to the first one, with an angle of 180°. The distance between these two points is the diameter of the circle, i.e. twice the radius, and it will be pointing away from the center of the circle. Since the center of rotation is one radius away, you obtain a total of $3r$ distance from the center.

Comment: If I draw all possible circles around the original circle, then they will be within a larger circle of radius *3r*. How can I describe this shape? what can I name it?

Comment: @Jolfaei: Not sure I understand your comment. I'd name this “circle of radius $3r$”, and I'd describe it as “the set no more than $3r$ away from the center of the original circle”. But I guess I'm missing something here. Please clarify what kind of description or name you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks. If each point is rotated with respect to its opposite point on the rim of the circle, then as the Euler angles are chosen randomly, the rotation trajectory will be a circle with radius *3r*. After drawing all such circles, it seems that the circle *3r* is rotating around the fixed circle *r*. Does such a shape have a dedicated name in geometry?

Answer (score 1):

A stab at an answer.  (happy to delete if unrelated).  I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, I am not a trained mathematician.  I am trying to decipher the properties of the ball below, and I looked up Euler angles, and wondered whether you are looking for an expansion pattern that is "clockwise/clockwise" counter balance hoarmonically.  (I am sure I am mangling the terminology, and I hope this is related.  your question sounds of a nature similar to a search I am on).

[image: Offset counter-rotating sphere]

Comment: thank you for sharing your research topic. I have read your post. Unfortunately, I have no knowledge regarding your problem, but I am sure if you break down your problem and simplify it, you may improve your chance to receive constructive answers. For instance, you may need to better explain what you mean by "properties" or What kind of mathematical properties you are looking at.